# $d_sg = 0$ for all $g$ in a (nontrivial) finite abelian group $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

We know for a finite nontrivial abelian group $G$ there exist positive integers $1 < d_1|...|d_s$ such that

$G \cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^{s} \mathbb{Z}/ d_i\mathbb{Z}$ and $|G| = d_1...d_s$

Now, I need to show that in such a group

$\forall g \in G \ \ d_sg = 0$, that is, $\forall g \in G \ \ |g|$ divides $d_s$.

By Lagrange's theorem $|g|$ divides $|G| = d_1...d_s$. Note that $d_i$'s doesn't have to be prime.

Comment: Write $g=(g_1,\dots,g_s)$. What is $dg$ for $d\in\mathbb Z$?

Comment: @user26857 So, we can view $g \in G$ as an element of $\bigoplus_{i=1}^{n} \mathbb{Z}/d_i \mathbb{Z}$, that is $([k_1]_{d_1}, ..., [k_s]_{d_s}) = k$. And since the groups are isomorphic, elements have the same order. Still, what is $(d_s[k_1]_{d_i}, ..., d_s[k_s]_{d_s})$? The order of $[k_i]_{d_i}$ is $\frac{d_i}{ \gcd(k_i, d_i) }$. We don't know that it divides $d_i$.

Comment: $d_i\mid d_s$, so $d_s=d_i\cdot \text{ something}$. Then what happens in $\mathbb Z/d\mathbb Z$ if you multiply every element by $d$? (Btw, $\frac dk\mid d$, don't you think?)

Comment: @user26857 Sorry, of course you are right. It's all simple when we write $g$ as $([k_1]_{d_1}, ..., [k_s]_{d_s})$. Surely, $d_i[k_i]_{d_i} = 0$, it's just that I was a little lost, a silly mind mistake, if I can say so myself. I got confused and forgot that $g^{|G|} = e_G$( Lagrange's theorem, thought we don't even need it in case of $\mathbb{Z}/ d \mathbb{Z}$) in a group $G$. Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

I'll expand on the hint of user26857 in the comments (since it's better if the question is to be officially answered in case someone will search for it and I'm not sure if he wants to write an answer). I thank him for the following idea.

So, we have that $G \cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^{n} \mathbb{Z}/ d_i \mathbb{Z}$.
To each $g \in G$ corresponds an (unique) element $([k_1]_{d_1}, ..., [k_s]_{d_s}) \in \bigoplus_{i=1}^{n} \mathbb{Z}/ d_i \mathbb{Z}$ send by an isomorphism.

These elements have the same order. And $$d_s([k_1]_{d_1}, ..., [k_s]_{d_s}) = 
(m_1d_1[k_1]_{d_1}, m_2d_2[k_2]_{d_2}, ..., d_s[k_s]_{d_s}) = ([0]_{d_1}, ..., [0]_{d_s} ),$$ so $d_s$ divides the order of $g$, hence, $d_sg = 0$.

Comment: Actually you already got $d_sg=0$; no need to mention that $d_s$ divides the order of $g$.

Comment: @user26857 Well, it's a technical detail. If we're being precise, the groups are not equal, but isomorphic. I got that $d_s([k_1]_{d_1}, ..., [k_s]_{d_s}) = ([0]_{d_1}, ..., [0]_{d_s})$ and that the orders of $([k_1]_{d_1}, ..., [k_s]_{d_s})$ and $g$ are the same since the order is preserved through an isomorphism. So I combined these two facts.